# Can you measure the voltage produced in the heart using an oscilloscope or multimeter

Tags: voltage-measurement, biopotential, voltage-source, ecg

Can you measure a PQRST wave using a multimeter or oscilloscope, it you can will two leads be enough and why are 12 leads standard tor ECG monitoring?

Comment: Multimeter?? No, definitely not. A high gain differential amplifier with very good line noise filtering is required. At least read the wikipedia article on [Electrocardiography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocardiography) as this explains about Wilson's Central Terminal and the various "leads". For medical diagnostics "leads" means someting different than "wires".

Comment: Be careful about isolation and mains earth leakage too, if you're experimenting.

Comment: An EKG with a display is basically an oscilloscope showing the output result of a group of differential amplifiers and filters.  In other words, an oscilloscope can display the QRST signal of the heart if you use the proper techniques to capture the QRST and separate it from the noise.

Answer (score 1):

I've used oscilloscopes on numerous occasions, to view the heart voltages.
Helps to have a differential plugin (Tek 7A22, e.g.) and certainly use a 3rd wire to the torso or leg to achieve a Ground.

Most important is R*C filtering to exclude cellphone and fluorescent light trash.
10Hertz LPF is about right.